# counting the number of terms that are not repeated in the python list

Tags: python, list, count, python-2.x

the question was actually like
Write a program that says the number of terms to be replaced to get all the numbers same in the list
ex
a=[1,1,2,1,1,4,1,1]
then the expected output is 2

Comment: what have you written so far?

Comment: Your question is not very well defined. What would happen in the case where there is more than one element repeated in the given list? For example, when trying to find how many replacements would be needed to make `[1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4]` homogeneous, should the answer be based of the `1`s or the `3`s?

Comment: no they gave an example where only one term is repeating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the minimum number of numbers to be replaced so that all numbers are the same.

```
# store occurrences of each number in a dictionary
d = {}
for i in a:
    if i not in d:
        d[i] = 1
    else:
        d[i] += 1

 # get key with max value: i.e. most frequent number in initial list
 max_k = max(d, key=d.get)

 # delete element that appears most often in the initial list
 del d[max_k]

 # count rest of the numbers => numbers to be replaced
 nums_to_replaces = sum([d[k] for k in d])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the list and make a dictionary of the occurrence:

```
occurrences = {}
for x in range(len(a)):
   if a[x] not in occurences:
      occurrences[x] = 1
   else:
      occurrences[x] += 1
```

Now you could have a dict of the occurrences and you could do this to get the number of terms to be replaced:

```
nums = list(occurrences.values()).sort(reverse=True) # Sort I descending order with num of repetitions
print(sum(nums[1:])) # Add occurrences of all but the element with max occurrences

#Or just subtract the max occurrence from the length of list

print(len(a) - max(list(occurrences.values())))
```

This will give you the least number of changes need to be made. In this way you cannot specify which element you want the whole list to contain

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is a bit strange.
If you want the number of items that are not one:

```
len([i for i in a if i!=1])
```

or

```
len(a)-a.count(1)
```

if you want the unique set of numbers that are not repeated as the question says:

```
len([i for i in set(a) if a.count(i)==1])
```

Comment: OP doesn't want number of values other than1. He wants to know how many numbers are there in the list other than the one which repeats the most, which might not be 1. If there is a list `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]` he want to know many many numbers need to be changed so the number becomes `[3,  3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`